# Retrieved DocumentID

Tags: document-id

I am using PowerShell to get a report of all the items in the document library. I managed to get most of the fields I wanted. However, I need help getting the document ID in my report.
In the report it just show empty value.

Kind regards

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using the Document ID Service? Try $Item.UniqueId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are diferent DocumentID values you can get from item:

- `_dlc_DocIdUrl` fully qualified URL for document referencing the DocIDRedir.aspx along with the lookup parameter
- `_dlc_DocId` The Document ID.  This is the internal property you can directly address and assign as `$item["_dlc_DocId"]`
- `_dlc_DocIdItemGuid` DocID related GUID

**Solution:**

Try `$Item["_dlc_DocId"]` or if you are using PNP powershell could be also `$Item.FieldValues["_dlc_DocId"]`

Comment: Thanks for your message. I used the $Item["_dlc_DocId"] since I am using Powershell, and it still returns null. Please see the screenshots.

Comment: Please check if you have Document ID Service enabled: Site Settings > Site Collection Features > Document ID Service.